# str_pad() to right is not working

Tags: php

```
$values = '';
str_pad( $values, 10, "?,", STR_PAD_RIGHT );
```

that is not padding anything , knowing that

> If the value of pad_length is negative, less than, or equal to the length of the input string, no padding takes place.

which is not in this case , so what is wrong here?

Comment: you need to echo str_pad()

Comment: `str_pad()` return value so you have to store return value in some variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the returned value from `str_pad` to `$values` as the method doesn't update by reference:

```
$values = '';
$values = str_pad( $values, 10, "?,", STR_PAD_RIGHT );
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/str_pad):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the padded string.